# Difference between setting a variable on init and overriding that variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, properties, overriding

I'm working on accessibility, and I see some code in a project I'm working on that's overriding the `isAccessibilityElement` variable. How is this different and/or why is this better than just setting the variable in the `init`?

This is what I see in my project:

```
public override var isAccessibilityElement: Bool 
{
  get { return false }
  set { }
}
```

How is it different from this?

```
public init()
{
  super.init(frame: .zero)
  isAccessibilityElement = false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer as I was asking the question.

When you write this code:

```
public override var isAccessibilityElement: Bool 
{
  get { return false }
  set { }
}
```

You prevent users of this view from changing that property by leaving the setter empty. If you just set the property in the `init`, then users of this class can still change that value, which could produce unwanted results.

However, doing it this way will also fail silently!!!

To reiterate: SETTING THIS VARIABLE WILL FAIL SILENTLY